# Date range picker and chart js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, daterangepicker, chartjs-2.6.0

I want to change the x-axis label on chart js according to my date range picker.If I select this week then x-axis label should started from sunday to saturday. If i select this month then the x-axis label should start from october 1.... october 30. If i select last month then it should be september 1..... september 30.
If i select date range then it should should from the starting month to ending month.

Till now i tried this but i know for sure. It is rubish.

```
$('#report-overview-range').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      let startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      let endDate = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      let date= startDate+'&'+endDate;
      $(this).attr('date', date);  
      let today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      let dateDiff = moment(today).diff(moment(startDate), 'days');
      /*If date difference is a 6 then its a week 
        if date difference is greater than 31 then its a */       
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

One way you could do this would be to dynamically assign the endpoint you want to get the data from.

```
$('#report-overview-range').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
    let startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let endDate = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let date = startDate + '&' + endDate;
    $(this).attr('date', date);
    let today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let dateDiff = moment(today).diff(moment(startDate), 'days');
    if (dateDiff < 6) {
        dataEndpoint = "weekRange.php?" + date;
        title = "Week View";
    } else {
        dataEndpoint = "monthRange.php?" + date;
        title = "Month View";
    }

    // assign a reference to the chart in the dom
    let chartRef = document.getElementById("chart-id-goes-here").getContext('2d');

    $.ajax({
        url: dataEndpoint,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (graphData) {
            new Chart(chartRef, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: Object.keys(graphData),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: title,
                        data: Object.values(graphData),
                    }] //end datasets
                }, //end data
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

In this example there's an if statement that changes the variable `dataEndpoint`.  I'm making some assumption on the way you're acquiring data, but the strategy should work in general.

If you map your x-axis to the keys and your y-axis to the pairs it will populate the table correctly using `Object.keys(graphData)` and `Object.values(graphData)` respectively.  Here's an example return for weekRange.php  (I tossed this into an existing project, that's affecting the CSS a little bit):

```
{
    "Sun":"41454.33",
    "Mon":"17546.34",
    "Tue":"12558.60",
    "Wed":"25757.79",
    "Thur":"26119.51",
    "Fri":"21195.63",
    "Sat":"20528.79"
}
```

And the chart after it's populated:
[image: chart.js dynamically populated x axis]

This is some junk data that monthRange.php returns:

```
{
    "1": "880.33",
    "2": "387.77",
    "3": "1056.54",
    "4": "48.58",
    "5": "1107.97",
    "6": "852.45",
    "7": "534.34",
    "8": "349.77",
    "9": "324.77",
    "10": "464.51",
    "11": "1135.88",
    "12": "514.75",
    "13": "278.85",
    "14": "176.22",
    "15": "167.96",
    "16": "424.49",
    "17": "1123.37",
    "18": "469.74",
    "19": "1844.47",
    "20": "346.86",
    "21": "424.05",
    "22": "664.59",
    "23": "985.48",
    "24": "1288.77",
    "25": "821.07",
    "26": "969.48",
    "27": "814.52",
    "28": "164.76",
    "29": "184.77",
    "30": "1730.73",
    "31": "657.75"
}
```

Here's what this data will look like on the same chart:
[image: chart.js dynamically populated x axis 2]

I'm not sure about `dateDiff` in this logic, I think you may need to rework it to return an integer.

Comment: okay i will view this later. Looks helpful. But can you please help me with this?.. I cannot remove all the labels and data on ajax. I used the function given on the documentation but its no use. it only pops up one label and one data. I want remove all the labels and data and create new

Comment: If you post more of your code we can work on it together.  I need to see the data you're working with, your data structure is going to affect your logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990134/chart-js-update-line-chart-having-two-data-sets i have asked it here