# Chart js: Update line chart having two data sets

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I want to update a line chart in chart js with two data sets. I've somehow managed to empty the chart and then able to fill in one of the data set. but unable to make both data sets working. here's the code.

```js
ajaxRequest(
    {
        url: 'reports/updateChart/?filter=true',
        method: 'post',
        data: data
    }, function (response)
        {
            /*refresh the tables with the new data sets*/
            removeData(myChart);
            let label = [1, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 234, 34, 234, 23, 23, 41, 3, 2, 4];
            let data = [234, 234, 5, 23, 34, 234, 234, 234],[22, 1, 123, 14, 2]
        }; addData(myChart, label, data);
    });

});
```

functions:

```js
function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels = [];
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data = [];
    });
    chart.update();
}

function addData(chart, label, data) {
    $.each(label, function (index, value) {
        chart.data.labels.push(value);
    });

    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            dataset.data.push(value);
        });
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

Comment: Is `data` really two data sets? And does the single dataset that you successfully plot include all the data from both datasets?

Comment: no .. single plotted dataset is just an single array.

Comment: Are you seeing 8 plotted points, or 13?

Comment: 8 plotted points from the first array. when i add second array like that it gives me an error

Comment: That's teh first time you have mentioned an error :-) Care to tell us what it says? That might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not able to find out the issue with your code, but you can refer the below way of updating charts which is very similar to what you have tried but this is working. You can refer the fiddle also -> http://jsfiddle.net/cuzx3L7j/4/

Hope it helps!

```
function clearAndAddNewDataSets() {
  myChart.config.data.datasets = [];
  myChart.config.data.labels = [];

  var labels = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3', 'Label4', 'Label5', 'Label6', 'Label8', 'Label8'];
  var data = [
    [234, 234, 5, 23, 34, 234, 234, 234],
    [22, 1, 123, 14, 2]
  ]

  var colors = ['Red', 'Green'];

  myChart.config.data.labels = labels;

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var dataSet = {
      label: 'testLabel' + i,
      data: data[i],
      backgroundColor: colors[i]
    }

    myChart.config.data.datasets.push(dataSet);
  }

  myChart.update();

}
```

Comment: Also there is no need to push value to the labels array, since your label variable is an array you can directly assign it like I have done

Comment: it helped me a lot but can you please look at this js fiddle. When i click update i want to just keep the old labels. I am getting old labels plus the new labels with extra color that is grey. I am sending two data but another array is getting pushed why? how to solve that too. https://jsfiddle.net/reyyoung/xpvt214o/906521/

Comment: Do you just want to update the data and xaxis labels? If yes -> https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/906629/

Comment: Thank you very much you have been a lot helpful

Comment: kunal. Now i am stuck at a point where my data points are hidding. If i select a date range from october 1 to september 31 then the label ranges from october 1,2............31 september 31.. it skipped all the dates after october 31 resulting no data points.